# Is there a way to make a session wait for all uncommitted transactions on a table in all other sessions to commit or rollback in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, transactions, commit

In Postgres.  I would to make my session wait until all uncommitted transactions of a table have been committed or rolled back. Is there a query I can run to detect any sessions that have uncommitted DML against the table and the start timestamp of the transaction.  I want to implement something similar to Oracle's  WAIT_ON_PENDING_DML function:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_UTILITY.html#GUID-314EDB9B-7948-4093-8A74-7159186168CE

I've been looking at the pg_locks view.  Not sure if I can use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that as follows:

```
SET lock_timeout = '1s';
LOCK tab IN SHARE MODE;
```

`SHARE` locks conflict with all DML, and the statement will terminate with an error if it cannot acquire a `SHARE` lock within one second.

Note that all other data modifying statements are blocked until the `LOCK` statement ends, which is different from what you want. You can do better by choosing a smaller `lock_timeout` and backing off for a while until you retry.

Comment: Yes thank you.  I was considering that but its a little more intrusive than the oracle library.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Well, you cannot expect everything to have an exact equivalent...